# GNS3 Lab over internet - Multi User

Tags: networking

My friend and I are both training for the CCNA Exam. We went through the Cisco classes together and now would like to make a production network. The only problem is we live in different houses. We have a server and I assume you can run GNS3 off of it. How would I make it so that we could each be on the server located at one house from a different house. Our main goal is to have a virtual network that we can access remotely outside of our networks. We would also like to run VM's on the server as well so we can make that production network(Windows Domains, Windows boxes, ect.).

So to summerize what I'm asking is how do we share a server located at one house and be able to log on to gns3 outside that home network and create a virtual lab with vm's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) solution like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) in the server, it will allow to connect from any device with internet access to the same LAN of the server (or the VLAN you specify).

I prefer OpenVPN instead any other vpn server because of the client software available for any device I use (mostly android and windows 7).

Comment: What about gns3 how would i set it up so that we both could be in the computer at the same time?

Comment: @apples I am not used to gns3 but it seems that no. Each user has his solely projects. Google says that you could [set up an multiuser environment](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/174140-43605/GNS3_multiuser_enviro..) but everything is about set up diferent environments. Maybe with [ubuntu and multiple x sessions](http://www.doknowevil.net/2010/10/13/multiple-x-desktop-sessions-in-ubuntu/) you could login as the same user and access to the same project,but you could have problems when saving changes to the same things at the same time,i really dont know,try!